# Fail compilation if a certain specialization is used

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to specialize a template in such a way that results in a compilation error when that specialization is instantiated? For example, I have a class for which `int`s don't make sense as a type:

```
class Careful
{
    template <typename T>
    void f(T value) { std::cout << "Non-specialized version"; }
};

template <>
void Careful::f(double value)
{
    std::cout << "specialization for double";
}

template <>
void Careful::f(int value)
{
    // make this one fail to compile
}
```

Is this possible somehow (ideally with a meaningful error message)?

Comment: Can you use C++11? static_assert then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want customized error messages, and can use C++11, you can go for the new `static_assert`:

```
class Careful
{    
    template <typename T>
    void f(T value) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "Don't call f with an int!");
    }
};
```

### EDIT

I thought I might explain one thing. Sure, it's possible to cause an error message for a given specialization, either by `static_assert`, `enable_if` or by not defining the function (these are the three answers which have been given). But I don't know of a way to *force* an error for a given specialization.

The `static_assert` and `enable_if` techniques are subject to SFINAE, so you won't get an error if someone later adds this function to the `Careful` class:

```
void f(int value)
{
    std::cout << "Overloaded!" << std::endl;
}
```

(I think that's a good thing, but it's still worth noting). Similarly, the code `template<> void Careful::f(int value);` is just a forward declaration for this specialization of `f` - later, someone could add a definition for it.

### Edit 2

Yeah this question looks answered, but I thought I should follow up with the most direct approach (and IMO, the "correct" approach): use `delete`.

```
class Careful
{
    template <typename T>
    void f(T value) { std::cout << "Non-specialized version"; }
};

template <>
void Careful::f(double value)
{
    std::cout << "specialization for double";
}

template <>
void Careful::f(int value) = delete;
```

`delete` works kind of like @hmjd's approach of not defining the function, but it *explicitly* says that no one can provide an implementation of the function. Also, the compiler message will be descriptive (note that it's a *compiler* error, not a *linker* error, so it's probably easier to find the source of the error). On g++, the error message for using the `delete`d function reads `error: use of deleted function ‘void Careful::f(T) [with T = int]’`. And if someone later tries to define the function elsewhere, they'll end up getter the error `redefinition of ‘void Careful::f(T) [with T = int]’` as opposed to no error at all.

Comment: Neat, hooray for C++11 :). Shouldn't the assert condition be inverted though? (I mean not negated as it is now)

Comment: @TamásSzelei: Yep, logical slip-up on my part. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [boost::enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) to produce a compile time error when a template is specialized for a specific type

Answer (score 2):

Declare the specialization but do not provide a definition will result in a failure:

```
template <>
void Careful::f(int value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can at least make linking fail. Just don't implement the function for the type(s), that makes no sense:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Careful
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void f(T value) { std::cout << "Non-specialized version"; }
};

template <>
void Careful::f(double value)
{
    std::cout << "specialization for double";
}

template <>
void Careful::f(int value); // int makes no sense. As long as you don't implement it for this type, compilation will fail at instantiation.

int main() {
    Careful x;
    x.f(3.14);
    x.f(42); // this will fail
}
```

with my g++, I get this error in the linking step:

```
 main.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `void Careful::f<int>(int)'
```

This is not a customized message, but the linking fails.

Comment: Compilation doesn't fail at instantiation. Compilation doesn't fail at all. It's *linking* that fails.

Comment: @Rob: right. I thought about deleting this answer, but it still might be helpful - for practical detection of the mis-use of **Careful.f<int>()**.

Comment: This can still be useful in some situations, and it is kind-of descriptive (by that I mean "not template-barf" :))